# NavigationLink repeats in swiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct Conte111ntView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View : click go to ThirdView ") .navigationBarTitle("Navigation").navigationBarHidden(true).gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{ v in
                    self.selection = "Third"
                }), tag: "Second", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }.isDetailLink(true)
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Third View  : click go to SecondView ") .navigationBarTitle("Navigation").navigationBarHidden(true).gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{ v in
                    self.selection = "Second"
                }), tag: "Third", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }.isDetailLink(true)
                Button("Tap to show second") {
                    self.selection = "Second"
                }
                Button("Tap to show third") {
                    self.selection = "Third"
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Navigation").navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Conte111ntView()
    }
}
```

I want to  Second View -> Third View
but  swiftUi  behavior is:   Second View -> rootView -> Third View

And quick tap  in 'click go to ThirdView' And ，'Third View'
it get the wrong  behavior 。  return to rootView

how can fix  this
Or am I doing it the wrong way？

Comment: Get rid of the buttons and the state protocol.

Comment: @El Tomato What to do

Comment: Would you describe what you try to achieve by this code? What is the goal behaviour?

Comment: i want to   Second View -> Third View    but swiftUi behavior is: Second View -> rootView -> Third View . @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simpler version.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("Second View : click go to ThirdView")
                }
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView()) {
                    Text("Third View  : click go to SecondView")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(false) 
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView is here!")
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ThirdView is here!")
    }
}
```

Comment: how to return  rootView?

Comment: I have made a one-line change.